# How can I get the icon of a notion page?

Tags: notion-api

According to the Notion Public API official documentation, I can retrieve a notion page.
But this [Page Object](https://developers.notion.com/reference/page) does not include the Icon of the page. The icon is usually a unicode character (like `\u2708\ufe0f` for ✈️). I was used to get this information with notion-py (the unofficial notion api client for python).

How can I retrieve this information with the public API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version of the API (Notion-Version: 2021-05-13) this is not supported. The page object does not have a page icon or banner image field. This may come in future iterations of the API as it is still in public beta.

Answer (score 3):

This looks to be possible now, as described in a blog post, https://developers.notion.com/changelog/page-icons-cover-images-new-block-types-and-improved-page-file-properties

> ### Page Icons and Cover Images
>
> When fetching a Page object or a Database object, the response will now include an icon and cover property, as shown below:
>
> ```json
> {
>     "object": "database",
>     "id": "96433ad8-3fbe-460f-a007-72311c4aa804",
>     "cover": {
>         "type": "external",
>         "external": {
>             "url": "https://website.domain/images/image.png"
>         }
>     },
>     "icon": {
>         "type": "emoji",
>         "emoji": ""
>     },
>     // ... remaining properties
> }
> ```

Comment: Yes, it's possible now. Just note that the URL for the image has an expiry from the time that it was generated in your api request to get the url.

Comment: I have built a simple data extractor using the official API that used to work beautifully, exactly as @Peet described above. However, as of recent (tried today), the icon property is now not accessible anymore, see [issue](https://github.com/makenotion/notion-sdk-js/issues/213). Anybody knows if the API is being updated?
This was also validated Postman. The API calls I tried include [Page](https://developers.notion.com/reference/retrieve-a-page), [Page Prop](https://developers.notion.com/reference/retrieve-a-page), and [DB](https://developers.notion.com/reference/retrieve-a-database).

Comment: @Janos sounds like they broke it... I'm using the same library for notion_export_enhancer to get the emoji icon

Comment: @Coburn, the [bug](https://github.com/makenotion/notion-sdk-js/issues/213) is now resolved! :)